# Repetition of an article "the" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

I have learned that the article "the" should be repeated if it each noun phrase describes quality of a noun in a separate sense. But I am not sure if second "the" is necessary in the following sentence:

"The first Phoenician state in North Africa and the former regional center of political and cultural primacy, Carthage was destroyed in 146 BC."

Should I omit the second "the" for a more clean structure or should I leave it there to emphasize the quality of Carthage?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Please take a moment to tour the site.  Is this a question about your own writing and style?

Comment: Yes, I need some clarifications about a sentence structure regarding the repetition of the article.